# Запятая в конструкции «только потому что»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Есть цитата (слова актрисы Кортни Кокс): "Я не могу быть с кем-то только потому, что у нас потрясающий секс".

Ставится ли там запятая после слова "потому" и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Ставится. По общему правилу.

> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «потому(,) что»,
>   выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_611

Как вариант запятая может стоять перед "потому что", в данном случае - перед "только потому что", но именно из-за наличия "только" такой вариант менее популярен, вплоть до того, что его отдельные "школьные" источники считают невозможным (хотя такая категоричность не совсем правильна, но для школьных целей приемлема).

> Запятая ставится после слова «потому»:
>
> ....
>
> 3. Выделительно-ограничительные или усилительные частицы «только», «лишь», «хоть», «все-таки», «просто», «прямо», «даже», «ведь» и пр.
>      находятся перед первым компонентом союза.

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/zapiataia-stavitsia-pered-potomu-chto-ili-posle.html

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчиненное предложение, в котором придаточная часть соединена с главной с помощью составного подчинительного союза **потому(,) что**.
Запятая, конечно же, ставится. Но вот где?

К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:
2) наличие перед союзом частиц (усилительных, ограничительных и др.):
*Неравнодушен я к ней **только потому, что** она ко мне равнодушна* (Эренбург); *Стоит ли отказываться от трудного дела **только потому, что** оно трудно?* (Крымов).

В нашем предложении запятая необходима после соотносительного слова "потому":
*Я не могу быть с кем-то **только потому, что** у нас потрясающий секс.*

Ты посидел, посмотрел на меня таинственно и сказал, что вызвал меня **только потому, что** хотел, чтобы я сам во всем честно разобрался. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 2 (1978)]

Нос с по-зверушечьи чуткими ноздрями, темнеющий пушок над губой, вызывающе вздёрнутый подбородок со вмятинкой ― всё как бы рассеяно, разбросано и присутствовало на лице **только потому, что** согласно природе обязано здесь присутствовать. [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)]

[Запятая при сложных подчинительных союзах](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138) (Розенталь)
Из Нацкорпуса: [только потому, что](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE&kwsz=5&p=3&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal)